# Is cocoon bootstrap compatible for windows 8.1 store apps?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, apache-cocoon

Is cocoon bootstrap compatible for windows 8.1 store apps? I am unable to get perfect answer. i have googled much.Kindly provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean: Cocoon apps use java, and there isn't a java implementation which supports Windows Store apps. You couldn't write a Windows Store app as a Cocoon app. You could host a web app or service written with Cocoon and connect to it from a Windows Store app written in Xaml & C++/C#/VB or HTML & JavaScript.

Documentation generally says what is supported rather than what isn't supported. You generally won't find links saying that something isn't supported, especially when it's not really in the same domain.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have used cocoon.dll for my windows store app for windows 8, can i use the same dll for windows 8.1 store app

Comment: If you can use it in a Windows Store app in Windows 8 you can probably to do the same in Windows 8.1. Run it through the WACK to confirm